# Google Cloud Function Authorization Failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Private Google Cloud Function. So I want to Authenticate to the Cloud Function with `Authorization: Bearer token` Header. But I'm getting `401 Unauthorized` as the response.

I created the private Cloud Function using:

```bash
gcloud beta functions deploy MyFunction --runtime go111--trigger-http --memory 128 --region us-central1 --source gs://bucketname/code.zip
```

I created a service account and assigned it permission to access the cloud function:

```bash
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding MyFunction --member=serviceAccount:cf-access@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/cloudfunctions.admin
```

Output:

```yaml
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:cf-access@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.admin
etag: BwWOGyVdpDg=
version: 1
```

Now, I downloaded the service account json file.

So now in order to access the Cloud Function, I will need to add the Authorization Header with Bearer token. For generating the bearer token, I use following java code:

```js
String fileName = "path/service-account.json";
FileInputStream keyFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(keyFileInputStream).createScoped(Collections.singleton(ContainerScopes.CLOUD_PLATFORM));    
credential.refreshToken();
String token = credential.getAccessToken();
```

I use this token in the Authorization Header.

> URL-
>
> us-central1-[project].cloudfunctions.net/MyFunction
>
> Header-
>
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.YpN3bEGV-H4WyTeLQn9kxxFq1Js7mcMtoESW1C-5HstmEgdaXR_gY_stxnlpJna8IL25VvnpwTg5tFL5OorcfBT2_Qtld7FViTbzHas4AiUUEme7mffXRtZOn29

I use Postman to send the request. For this request, I get the output:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
        <h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL 
            <code>/MyFunction</code>.
        </h2>
        <h2></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

What could be wrong? Is the token generation logic something different?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of OAuth tokens. Refresh Token, Access Token, Identity Token.

You are trying to use an OAuth Access Token instead of an OAuth Identity Token.

For Authorization, Google Cloud Functions uses an OAuth Identity Token in the `authorization: bearer` HTTP header.

In your question, you do not show setting up IAM member access to the Cloud Function. That means no matter what Identity Token you use, all will be denied.

Comment: Hi John, the cf-access@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com email is a Service account with admin access to cloud function as mentioned in the question

Comment: @user5155835 If you are using the wrong OAuth Token, the roles that your service account has does not matter. You can create a service account with zero roles and still be authorized based upon Identity for IBAC (Identity Based Access Control), which you are trying to use.

Comment: @user5155835 - I have written several articles on this topic for Cloud Run which implements the same IBAC features as Cloud Functions: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```vb
Private Shared Async Function GetAccessToken(pCredentialJson As String, pFunctionPath As String) As Task(Of String)
    Try
        Dim scopes = New String() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing"}
        Dim credential As ServiceAccountCredential = TryCast(GoogleCredential.FromJson(pCredentialJson).CreateScoped(scopes).UnderlyingCredential, ServiceAccountCredential)
        Dim oidcToken = Await credential.GetOidcTokenAsync(OidcTokenOptions.FromTargetAudience(pFunctionPath))
        Return Await oidcToken.GetAccessTokenAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

Put the value returned in header Authorization `Bearer ...`.