# Google Cloud Platform - cloud functions API - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm struggling with invoking GCP cloud functions via REST API using Java.

The steps that I've performed to do it were:

- create a service account with role "Cloud Functions Invoker"
- download JSON key file for the newly created service account
- in my code, obtain an access token using the following method:

```
private String getAuthToken() {
  File credentialsPath = new File(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY_FILE);

  GoogleCredentials credentials;
  try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
    return credentials
           .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))
           .refreshAccessToken()
           .getTokenValue();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Action could not be performed");
  }
}
```

- perform a REST call, using the created token:

```
public <Payload, Response> ResponseEntity<Response> callCloudFunction(
    String endpoint,
    Payload payload,
    Class<Response> klazz
) {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  String url = gCloudUrl + endpoint;
  String token = getAuthToken();
  String payloadString = null;

  if (payload != null) {
    try {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      payloadString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not perform action");
    }
  }

  headers.add("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token));
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(payloadString, headers);

  return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, klazz);
}
```

The implementation looks fine, but in response I'm getting 401 Unauthorized.

Unfortunately, GCP documentation is not really helpful. I think I've searched through all the possible places.

Comment: Here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64720883/14592586
See if it helps in solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, agree, it's not clear...

Then, you have to know (and it's not clear again) that you need an access token to call Google Cloud API, but and identity token to call IAP (on App Engine for example) or private Cloud Function and Cloud Run. And this identity token need to be signed by Google.

And, as mentioned in the code, you need to have a service account on your computer, but I recommend you to avoid this on GCP, it's not required if you use default authentication (see my code, on your computer set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var that points to the service account key file). The best way is to not use service account key file on your computer also, but it's not yet possible (that is a security issue IMO, and I'm discussing with Google on this...)

Anyway, here a code snippet which works in Java (nowhere in the documentation...)

```
  String myUri = "https://path/to/url";
  // You can use here your service account key file. But, on GCP you don't require a service account key file.
  // However, on your computer, you require one because you need and identity token and you can generate it with your user account (long story... I'm still in discussion with Google about this point...)
  Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
  IdTokenCredentials idTokenCredentials = IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
    .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
    .setTargetAudience(myUri).build();

  HttpRequestFactory factory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(new HttpCredentialsAdapter(idTokenCredentials));

  HttpRequest request = factory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(myUri));
  HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
  System.out.println(CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8)));
```

*NOTE* If you want to continue to use RestTemplate object and set manually your token, you can generate it like this

```
  String token = ((IdTokenProvider) credentials).idTokenWithAudience(myUri, Collections.EMPTY_LIST).getTokenValue();
  System.out.println(token);
```

Comment: I can't believe this, but it works like a charm :D My IDE only warns that `IdTokenProvider` is marked as unstable (due to `@Beta` annotation) but, honestly, I don't care ;) I've done dozens of attempts on this topic. Your help is priceless :)

Comment: @guillame, thanks for being a hero and demystifying this google auth madness. However, throughout the various StackOverflow posts, I don't see a good suggestion on how to make this interoperable and seamless when switching between dev/test/GCP environments. Any suggestions?

Comment: The key, in Java or in other language, is to rely on the ADC (Application Default Credential) that you get like this `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()`. Thus, your application rely on the environment configuration. In dev environment, you are on the dev project. You deploy with the service account dedicated to the project and the application use it automatically because it belongs to the environment context. Same things for the other environment. If you have a specific use case, or blocker, feel free to share it (in a new question and paste the link here!)

Comment: Problem is that `gcloud auth application-default login` launches a browser that forces you to pick a Google user account. When set this way, the `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()` method returns an instance of `com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials` instead of the required `IdTokenProvider`. Therefore, setting the environment variable or the path to the service account JSON file seems to be required locally. I was able to "trick" it by manually copying a service account file to one that's called `application_default_credentials.json` but that seems a bit ew. :)

Comment: ... I know... I'm going to solve this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/pull/469 You can upvote or comment this merge request to speed up its validation! I don't know why it's not by default in the auth-library. Any language offer the capability to generate a valid ID-TOKEN with a user credential although the gcloud SDK can (gcloud auth print-identity-token)

Comment: You can also have a look to [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c)