# Receiving 401 when accessing authenticated Google Cloud Function

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to invoke an authenticated HTTP-based cloud function from another cloud function. Let's call them CF1 and CF2 respectively, for the sake of brevity; thus I wish to invoke CF2 from CF1.

Following the example given by the Google Documentation: [Authenticating for Invocation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#functions-bearer-token-example-java), I created a new service account for CF2, and then attached it to CF1 with the `roles/cloudfunctions.admin` . I downloaded a service key for local testing with *Functions Framework*, setting it as the Application Default Credentials(ADC); thus CF2 on my local machine connects to CF1 on GCP, authenticating as CF2's service account via ADC.

I have deployed CF1 on Cloud Functions successfully, and was testing whether CF2 on my local machine could reach to CF1 when I was surprised to receive a HTTP 401.

For reference, here is the code in question, which is almost identical to the samples provided by the Google Documentation:

```java
        String serviceUrl = "<cf1-url>";
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

        if (!(credentials instanceof IdTokenProvider)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Credentials are not an instance of IdTokenProvider.");
        }

        IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
                IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                        .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
                        .setTargetAudience(serviceUrl)
                        .build();

        GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl(serviceUrl);
        HttpCredentialsAdapter adapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(tokenCredential);
        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory(adapter).buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = request.execute();
```

I tried referring to:

- [Google Cloud Platform - cloud functions API - 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863140/google-cloud-platform-cloud-functions-api-401-unauthorized)
- [Cloud Function Permissions (403 when invoking from another cloud function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142729/cloud-function-permissions-403-when-invoking-from-another-cloud-function)
- [Google Cloud Function Authorization Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125081/google-cloud-function-authorization-failing?rq=1)

but I was not able to find a solution to my problem from those questions.

Further testing revealed that the identity token generated via the client SDK:
`tokenCredential.getIdToken().getTokenValue()` is different from the GCloud CLI command `gcloud auth print-identity-token`. I could use the identity token generated by GCloud CLI to directly invoke CF1 (e.g. via Postman/cURL and authenticated as CF2's service account) but not the identity token printed by the client SDK. This was a surprise as I am using CF 2's service account keys as the ADC, and also authorized it for gcloud access via `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

It seems to me that there is no issue with the permissions of the service accounts and cloud functions, as I can directly invoke CF1; thus it would appear to be an issue with the code. However, I am unable to determine the cause of the 401 error.

Comment: Did you check the principal of the idenitty token generated by your java app? Are you sure that this idenitty is authorized?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, sorry I am not that familiar with OAuth. If by principal you are referring to the "audience" field of the credentials, then I have set it to CF1's URL. If by principal you are referring to the user of the identity token, then I had a look at the JWT received and verified via its email field that the token is issued for CF 2's service account, which is a cloud-functions-admin on CF1. And since I can invoke CF1 as CF2's service account via the gcloud CLI, then it appears to me that so far there is no issue with the permissions and identity.

Comment: GCloud and ADC (application default credential) aren't the same. You can have 2 different ones with gcloud (`gcloud auth login` for gcloud CLI command (like gcloud auth print-identity-token) and `gcloud auth application-default login` for app and code that use the Google Cloud Client libraries -> your case). That's why, the email of the token generated by your java code is important, you need to be sure that this email is authorized to call the target function.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for your reply. The reason I am sure the email is authorized to access the function, is because I am authenticated on gcloud via `gcloud auth activate-service-account`, which if i understood correctly from [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account), performs the same function as `gcloud auth login`, except that I am using service account credentials instead of user account credentials.

Comment: To confirm, I used `gcloud config list` and verified that the account used in the `account` field is the service account of CF 2. Thus, it is my understanding that the identity token printed using `gcloud auth print-identity-token` is indeed the identity token of the CF 2's service account. This service account is also set as the ADC, and the `client_email` field of the JWT received from Google APIs has also been verified to be the CF2's service account.

Comment: Ok, now try to set the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL=/path/to/file.json` and run again your Javacode (you can only set the env var in your IDE like intelliJ when you run your java code)

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for replying. Actually, my env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` was already set to CF2's service account key file when i invoked the code. This was how I originally set my ADC to point to the service account. For reference, I am using a Windows machine; and when running my IDE debugger I can confirm that the code `GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();` is pointing to the service account key file that is referenced in the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL` env var.

Comment: Ok, I re-read your question with these information and it's clearer now. But it's still strange. the cf1 serviceURL is the raw URL or did  you add some parameters?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Oh goodness, you are right, it is not the raw URL! There were query parameters in the URL and I was totally unaware(and slightly embarrassed) that they would affect the identity token; it is working now! I would be pleased if you could post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: No worries, if I know that it's because I performed the same mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target audience, your `serviceURL`, must be the raw url, this one provided by the Cloud Functions service.

If you add your parameters (query or path) it won't work.